# map inside map in C++ . Pretty confusing?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I am little confused here one map which has name myMap is a map inside map
 obviously on value side while the second map is a 
very normal map of int vs char . 
No in one case (which is myMap) it is allowing 
duplicate keys (abnormal behaviour) while in another case it doesn't .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map> 
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{ 
    map<int, map<int,char> > myMap;   // map inside map
    map<int, char> ourMap;            // normal map

    myMap[1][1] = 'A';
    myMap[1][2] = 'B';     // should overwrite  previous value
    myMap[2][1] = 'C';
    myMap[2][2] = 'D';     // should overwrite  previous value

    ourMap[1] = 'A';
    ourMap[1] = 'B';

    cout << "[1][1] = " << myMap[1][1] << endl;
    cout << "[1][2] = " << myMap[1][2] << endl;
    cout << "[2][1] = " << myMap[2][1] << endl;
    cout << "[2][2] = " << myMap[2][2] << endl;

    cout << "ourMap[1] = " << ourMap[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
// And here is the output . By the way I was anticipating , [1][2] = B , [2][2] = D & ourMap[1] = B . But something else comes out . 

OUTPUT :

[1][1] = A
[1][2] = B
[2][1] = C
[2][2] = D
ourMap[1] = B
```

Is if we have map inside map does in C++ they start deviating from their normal behavior which is can't have duplicate keys 
I am not able to figure it out how it is so . Can anyone tell me how it is so ? Extremely sorry if the question sounds funny ?

```
My Question is for myMap 
myMap[x][y] = something
u can have only distinct value of x ?
For normal map it is like that only .
```

Comment: Rest assured there's no key duplication or deviant behaviour going on

Comment: "myMap[1][2] = 'B';     // should overwrite  previous value" - why?

Comment: Why do you expect that `myMap[1][2] = 'B'` should overwrite `myMap[1][1] = 'A'`?

Comment: My Question is for myMap 
myMap[x][y] = something
u can have only distinct value of x ?
For normal map it is like that only .

Comment: There _is_ only one distinct value of x.

Answer (score 3):

You're imagining a problem where none exists.

There are no "duplicate keys".

Your container could be visualised thus:

```
"myMap"                              map<int, map<int,char>>
  |
  +-- [1]  "myMap[1]"                map<int,char>
  |          |
  |          +-- [1]  "myMap[1][1]"  char
  |          |
  |          +-- [2]  "myMap[1][2]"  char
  |
  +-- [2]  "myMap[2]"                map<int,char>
             |
             +-- [1]  "myMap[2][1]"  char
             |
             +-- [2]  "myMap[2][2]"  char
```

On this line:

```
myMap[1][1] = 'A';
```

you access (and, since it doesn't exist yet, create) `myMap[1]`.

Then, with `myMap[1]`, you access key 1 of the *inner* map and assign `'A'`.

Next, on this line:

```
myMap[1][2] = 'B';
```

you again access `myMap[1]`. Nothing needs to be "overwritten"; you're just accessing the first element in `myMap[1]` again.

This time, you access key 2 of the inner map and assign `'B'`.

---

Here's another way of writing your code, using references to get a clearer name for those inner maps:

```
map<int,char>& firstInnerMap = myMap[1];
firstInnerMap[1] = 'A';
firstInnerMap[2] = 'B';

map<int,char>& secondInnerMap = myMap[2];
secondInnerMap[1] = 'C';
secondInnerMap[2] = 'D';
```

---

Alternatively, consider a `map<int, string>`:

```
map<int, string> myMap;
myMap[1] = "Hello";
myMap[1][0] = 'J';   // change string to "Jello"
```

We've accessed the string "called" `myMap[1]` and performed an operation on it (`theString[0] = 'J'`). This has no effect on `myMap`. No "overwriting" needs to occur.

When you're nesting a map instead, it's no different.

Answer (score 1):

OK:

```
   myMap[1][1] = 'A';
```

when these functions are first called, myMap is empty. So,

```
   myMap[1]     // XXXX
```

creates an entry in that map with index 1. The thing created is itself a map. Then:

```
   myMap[1][1] = 'A';
```

creates an entry within the second, contained, map, and assigns 'A' to it.

Then

```
     myMap[1][2] = 'B';
```

looks up the map entry created at XXX with index 1 (which is itself a map) and adds an entry with key 2 and value B to that second, contained map.

So we have one entry in the top-level map, and two entries in the second level one.

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` operator does a find and insert if not found. It returns an iterator to a value given a key.

Thus doing `myMap[1]` returns an iterator to a `map<int,char>`.

Then doing `myMap[1][1]` returns an iterator to a char as the second `[]` is being called on the iterator returned from `myMap[1]`.

So doing `myMap[1][1] = 'A'` and `myMap[1][2] = 'B'` is no different than `ourMap[1] = 'A'` and `ourMap[2] = 'B'`.